How to remove shadow of bottomSheetwith flutter 3.24
After update flutter to 3.24 get some problem I don't know how to solve that try every thing but I don't find any solve to this issue.
I get backgrund color or shadow color around button in bottomSheet when use bottomSheet I don't know why, But I found this topic in github attached link below , they are talking about the same problem but I did not find a solution for it.See the white color around the button in picture. Attached is a picture of the code for the entire page to clarify the problem.
Link:
BottomSheet has incorrect shadow compared M3 spec

Flutter 3.24.5 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision dec2ee5c1f (3 weeks ago) • 2024-11-13 11:13:06 -0800
Engine • revision a18df97ca5
Tools • Dart 3.5.4 • DevTools 2.37.3



void main() {
  runApp(const testpage());
}

class testpage extends StatefulWidget {
  const testpage({super.key});

  @override
  State<testpage> createState() => _nnnsState();
}

class _nnnsState extends State<testpage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
        bottomSheet: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
          child: Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            child: FloatingActionButton.extended(
              onPressed: () {},
              elevation: 0,
              label: Text(
                "Next",
              ).tr(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}



Does anyone have a solution to remove the white color and make it transparent without any color?

follow the code standard
Write your app code standard
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const TestPage());
}

class TestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<TestPage> createState() => _TesState();
}

class _TesState extends State<TestPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
        bottomSheet: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
          child: Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            child: FloatingActionButton.extended(
              onPressed: () {},
              elevation: 0,
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              label: const Text(
                "Next",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}



